# Uniqueness of continuation of the exponential function.

Tags: complex-analysis, exponential-function

Assume that you have proved a complex-valued function $f$ to be equal to $e^x$ on the real line. Is it possible to conclude that $f$ is equal to $e^x$ on whole $\mathbb{C}$ and why / why not?

Maybe I do not see a simple solution. Since the real numbers do not lie dense in the complex plane, the only criterion I am able to remember cannot be applied.

In addition I am interested if the solution of my first question can be easily changed to fit for $e^{ax}$, $a \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$. But I will think about it if I have an answer for the other question.

The question arose during an exercise lesson, noone including the trainer was able to answer it.

Comment: If you only require "a function" or even "a continuous function" the answer is "no".  As Kava Rama Murthy suggests, you need "an analytic function".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define $f(x)=0$ for all $x$ not on the real line to get a different extension. If there is no assumption on what type of extension you want there is no uniqueness.

However If $f$ is analytic on the complex plane and $f(x)=e^{x}$ for $x$ real then the same equation is true for all complex $x$ by the Identity Theorem.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem

Comment: It's to late in the night, I simply forgot to add the analycity condition. Thanks!